# CSS positioning problem

Tags: css

I have a DIV within which I place form controls using `style:position: absolute;top ... etc`

and after the DIV I want a single paragraph.

I was expecting

```
---------------
|             |
|   DIV       |
---------------

PARA
```

but am getting

```
---------------
| PARA        |
|   DIV       |
---------------
```

Comment: please post what you have or snip of it on http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: What you have now doesn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must manually set the `height` of the `div` to however high it should be based on what's inside it. Once you do this, the paragraph will be placed below the `div`.

[Without a `height`](http://jsfiddle.net/RE6qF/) versus [with a `height`](http://jsfiddle.net/RE6qF/1/).

It's either that, or don't place your "form controls" with `position: absolute`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that when you set the div to position absolute, the rendering engine removes it from the relative positioning system, so your div doesn't reserve it's own height and width relative to adjacent elements... you have to set the height of the div statically, or add a padding to the inside of the container that is set to accommodate the general size of the div.

Answer (score 1):

If the position is absolute, the element is not affected by positioning of others elements and others too. You can put the paragraph inside de DIV and use position relative on this paragraph.

Try this:

```
<style type="text/css">
    #box {
        position:absolute;
        top:15px;
        left:40px;
        border:1px solid red;
        width: 40px;
        height: 40px;
    }
    #paragraph{
        position: relative;
        top:30px;
    }
</style>
<div id="box">
    <p id="paragraph">my paragraph</p>
</div>
```